# WebdriverIO autocomplete in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, wdio-v5

I am wonder, if it is way how to enable autocompletion for WDIO global variables ( `$`, `$$`, `browser` ) in VSCode. I know, that wdio has support for [Webstorm](https://webdriver.io/docs/autocompletion.html), but it doesn't work for VSCode.

Any idea, how to use autocompletion in VSCode? Without it is pretty hard to create some tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled with this as well. Firstly, ensure you've followed the ["Autocompletion" Setup](https://webdriver.io/docs/autocompletion.html) described on the website; for example, they require something like the following exist in a file called **`jsconfig.json`** at the root of your project:

```
{
  "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.json",
    "node_modules/@wdio/sync",
    "node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework"
  ]
}
```

You may already have a `jsconfig.json`; if so, ensure that the `node_modules` directories are **not** in a section called `"exclude": { ... }`. When setting up other things like Babel (for mocha) this may get installed as a default configuration entry. When `node_modules` is in both `include` and `exclude`, **`exclude`** takes precedence.

I had zero success importing npm `@types` pacakges, adding `typeAcquisition: {}` to `jsconfig.json`, or adding `interface browser;` into the file `global.d.ts` as other people have suggested in various forums.

Comment: Removing `node_modules` from exclude section helped me to make types work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Auto completion is pre-installed on  vs code.  If it is not working you might want to check through extension and install.  And to use, once the open tag is created,  it often auto suggest,  just do appropriately then input your attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but it doesn't know global variables. It works properly, if you want autosuggestion on imported object, but on global var, it is something else.